# Difference between list and char memory allocation

Tags: python, memory, memory-management

```
def f(b, a=[]):
    a.append(b)
    print('a : ', a)
f(1)
f(2)

# >> a : [1]
# >> a : [1, 2]
```

I thought variable 'a' remained in memory because GC or Reference Count didn't activate.

```
def f(b, a=''):
    a += b
    print('a : ', a)

f('1')
f('2')

# >> a : 1
# >> a : 2
```

result of this function is different. variable a initialized each time of calling function.

memory of dictionary, set, list were remained after calling function. but int, string was cleared.
is it different memory allocation system?

Comment: In a nutshell: `list.append` modifies the object in-place. But Python strings are immutable, and `+=` creates and assigns a new value.

Comment: @KonradRudolph thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is list is a mutable object. On the first call a  is initialized and in subsequent calls it is referenced. int and str are immmutable as you can see from below:

```
>>> str1 = 'hello'
>>> id(str1)
1900958690736
>>> str1 = 'how r u'
>>> id(str1)   # is a different string now
1900958712176
```

In order to achieve what you are looking for you can use:

```
def f(b, a=None):
    if not a:
        a = []
    a.append(b)
    print('a : ', a)
f(1) # a :  [1]
f(2) # a :  [2]
```